# Using an interactive shell with appium and python

Tags: android, python, ios, appium

I'm writing automated tests for our Android and iOS apps and I was wondering if there was an interactive shell in python for appium where you can run the app you are testing against and query the screen for certain elements. I know you can use 'arc' in ruby that let's you query the screen on the device for certain elements, but I can't find anything similar for python.

Comment: Well you can always use the poor man method of plain old Python shell invoking the Appium Python bindings (or WebDriver Python bindings using RemoteWebDriver against Appium), and starting Appium with your target app. It will allow you to interact w/ the target app through Appium over a shell, you just don't get any nice integrated UI inspector is all.

Comment: You probably should post this question to the Appium discussion forum: https://discuss.appium.io, if you haven't already better response there I figure.